# GitHub - Error: (/github/workspace/./_config.yml): mapping values are not allowed in this context

Tags: github, jekyll

I'm unfamiliar with GitHub and having an error while building an online CV using jekyll.

The error message is:

```
Error:  (/github/workspace/./_config.yml): 
mapping values are not allowed in this context.
```

What is causing this error and how can I resolve it?

Not sure if this is enough context, but I'm happy to provide the reciprocity to get some help with figuring it out.

Comment: What does that file contain? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your yaml workflow file for your GitHub Action (using for instance [YAML Lint](http://www.yamllint.com/) or [YAML Validator](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator))

That will tell you if something is misplaced, and would explain the error message.